# Count the number of occurances of data across multiple fields

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to count the number of times a value occurs across a number of fields as in the picture, which is a table called OptionsData.

[image]

I have a table called tblSubjects and this counts all from Choice1.

```
SELECT tblSubjects.subject, Count(OptionsData.Choice1) AS CountOfChoice1
FROM OptionsData 
INNER JOIN tblSubjects ON OptionsData.Choice1 = tblSubjects.subject
GROUP BY tblSubjects.subject;
```

but I am struggling to include counting Choice2, 3 and 4 in the query for an overall total.

Comment: What does the table have to do with the query?

Comment: Which table - the picture? This is the table OptionsData.

Comment: Start by normalizing that table. Then you won't have this problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use a subquery to merge the four choices into 2 columns (choice and choice count):

```
select ts.subject, sum(choice_cnt)
from
tblsubjects ts
INNER JOIN
(
SELECT choice1 as choice, count(*) as choice_cnt
FROM OptionsData 
GROUP BY choice1
UNION ALL
SELECT choice2, count(*)  
FROM OptionsData 
GROUP BY choice2
UNION ALL
SELECT choice3, count(*)  
FROM OptionsData 
GROUP BY choice3
UNION ALL
SELECT choice4, count(*)  
FROM OptionsData 
GROUP BY choice4 ) tblchoice
ON ts.subject = tblchoice.choice
group by ts.subject;
```

Caution: not test on ms-access.

Answer (score 0):

Probably not the fastest execution but simple:

```
SELECT subject,
 DCOUNT("OptionsDataID","OptionsData","Choice1='" & [subject] & "'")+DCOUNT("OptionsDataID","OptionsData","Choice2='" & [subject] & "'")+DCOUNT("OptionsDataID","OptionsData","Choice3='" & [subject] & "'")+DCOUNT("OptionsDataID","OptionsData","Choice4='" & [subject] & "'") AS CountOfChoices
FROM tblSubjects
```

The above assumes that `subject` is Text (really bad design you should have numerical IDs for linking to other tables not text) and that there is at least a unique numerical ID column in `OptionsData`.

Overall, your design is flawed in many ways. If you are not commited to the specific structure I would suggest you restructure everything. Add Numerical ID to subjects and each of your choices should be a single record in a table that would probably just include ChoiceID (autonumber), StudentID (or whatever other data entity the choices refer to) and SubjectID.

In a design like this not only would your current problem be a non-issue, but you would not be limited to a fixed number of 4 choices.